# gradle-ssh-plugin ssh.settings syntax in kotlin

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-ssh-plugin

I am trying to configure the gradle-ssh-plugin within my build.gradle.kts in kotlin.

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/int128/gradle-ssh-plugin/issues/317#issuecomment-1691195984), which helped me a lot.
Everything is working fine as long as I put my known host entries in the standard location of the plugin `knownHosts: new File("${System.properties['user.home']}/.ssh/known_hosts"),`.

But I want to configure a different location for this file, as I want to place the file into the git repo.

But no matter what I set into the settings, it is still using the standard location.
I have tried the following ways:

```
tasks.create("deploy") {

        val myServer = Remote(
                mapOf<String, String>(
                        "host" to "192.168.1.1",
                        "user" to "username",
                        "password" to "password"))


        doLast {

            ssh.run(delegateClosureOf<RunHandler> {
                settings(
                        delegateClosureOf<PerServiceSettings>{
                            mapOf(
                                    "knownHosts" to AllowAnyHosts.instance,

                                    )
                        }
                )
                session(
                        myServer,
                        delegateClosureOf<SessionHandler> {
                    put(
                            hashMapOf(
                                    "from" to "${project.rootDir}/deploy",
                                    "into" to "/home/username/"))
                })
            })
        }

    }
```

and

```
tasks.create("deploy") {

        val myServer = Remote(
                mapOf<String, String>(
                        "host" to "192.168.1.1",
                        "user" to "username",
                        "password" to "password"))
        ssh.settings (
                    delegateClosureOf<GlobalSettings>{
                        mapOf(
                                "knownHosts" to AllowAnyHosts.instance,

                        )
                    }
            )


        doLast {

            ssh.run(delegateClosureOf<RunHandler> {

                session(
                        myServer,
                        delegateClosureOf<SessionHandler> {
                    put(
                            hashMapOf(
                                    "from" to "${project.rootDir}/deploy",
                                    "into" to "/home/username/"))
                })
            })
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val myServer = Remote(
                mapOf<String, String>(
                        "host" to "192.168.1.1",
                        "user" to "username",
                        "password" to "password"
                        "knownHosts" to AllowAnyHosts.instance                       ))
```

move the configuration to Remote,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).